# DCOM Error Based on Number of Users

Tags: remote-server, dcom

I have an application that uses a DCOM component to get data from remote machines. A client is getting strange behavior when using this app on Windows Server 2012. The first 12 users to connect via RDP can use the app just fine but the 13th user is not able to connect to the remote machines: "DCOM got error 2147500058 from the computer XXX when attempting to activate the server". The exception logged by my app reports "RPC server unavailable". There is no firewall to contend with, and it is not specific to any remote machine. It appears to be strictly based on the number of users running the app. If one of the original 12 logs off, the (originally) 13th one can then connect just fine. There also does not appear to be a problem with memory or CPU usage.

Does anyone have a clue for what I should look for? This is kind of outside my knowledge base and I'm not really sure what I can even look for at this point.

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this ends up being helpful to anyone else, I did resolve this issue. It turned out to be a lack of dynamic ports on the system. Running the following set of commands resolved the issue for me:

netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000

netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=50000

netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000

netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=50000

Thanks to anyone who may have looked into this.

Dennis